# Java Collections.checked*() vs Generic collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

Java's Collections.checked*() api gives us type-safe views to underlying collections. But the checks happen at runtime and throw a runtime exception which can be costly for performance. The same type checking can be enforced at compile time by giving a specific type to those collections by using generic collections. So are there situations where Collections.checked*() scores over generic collections with their types specified?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The javadoc explains it well:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29

> The generics mechanism in the language provides compile-time (static) type checking, but it is possible to defeat this mechanism with unchecked casts. Usually this is not a problem, as the compiler issues warnings on all such unchecked operations. There are, however, times when static type checking alone is not sufficient. For example, suppose a collection is passed to a third-party library and it is imperative that the library code not corrupt the collection by inserting an element of the wrong type.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that the compile-time check can easily be circumvented, both accidentally and consciously.

The compiler *will* warn you, if that happens, but warnings are easily ignored and the problem might happen in some library somewhere. The type-information provided by generics **is** reliable, but *only* if all the code involved compiles without any warnings related to generics: no unchecked casts, no raw types.

Using `Collections.checked*()` gives you a way to enforce the restriction, even when using code that's outside of your control (as long as you can pass in a collection of your own).

Answer (score 2):

When using an old library with unchecked types in a new 1.5+ project.

Comment: because you happen to work in a financial company, when you need to beg to change a library, and face a several months bureaucratic process.Yeah, you're right, I should get a better job....

Answer (score 2):

Collectons.checkedXxxxx() performs runtime checks are provides extra safety.  The compiler can be avoided by using type erasure, however the checked collections should always check the type is correct.

I doubt the performance difference is enough to worry about. It is likely to be about 10 ns or less.